# c++ push_back doesn't work as it is supposed

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class symbol_table that has a vector of objects of another class row_st.also I have an enter method where inserts objects of row_st with a passed name into the vector of desired symbol_table.but when I call the enter to enter objects with name :
a;b;c;Iwill get the following result: a,b,c;b,c;c.the first element of vector gets the name of all the entered objects. and the second element also gets the name of the later entries.

```
  class row_st
  {
   public:
      char* name;
      type_u type;//int:0,flaot:1;char:2,bool:3,array:
      int offset;
      symbol_table *next;
      symbol_table *current;
  };
  class symbol_table
  {
   public:
    vector <row_st *> row;
     int type;
     int header;
     int starting_stmt;
     int index;
     int i;
     symbol_table *previous;
     symbol_table(){ header=0;
      previous=0; index=0;i=0;starting_stmt=0;}
  };
```

and here it is the enter method:

```
 int enter(symbol_table *table,char* name,type_u type){
     row_st *t=new row_st;
t->name=name;
t->type=type;
t->offset=table->index;
t->current=table;
table->index++;
t->next=0;
table->row.push_back(t);
table->header +=1;
return table->row.size()-1;
   }
```

the push_backed elements all points to the same address.the new call makes the same row_st every time it is called.what should I do?

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary blank lines from your code - they make it very difficult to read.

Comment: Could you show us exactly how you call the above code? I would guess that you need to copy the strings that you pass in, either on the calling side or inside enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neil Butterworth's answer suggest, the trouble is probably not with this code, but the place where you call it. Using character pointers does not make it impossible to make things work, just harder.

The problem in this case is definitely *not* with push_back. If you posted the method where you call this code it might be possible to see exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: the problem is that I can't remove char*.since enter is called in a c based program. I don't guess the problem is with char*,pushback has a destructor that deletes after adding. isn't there the problem?

Comment: @angela: Just make `row_st::name` a `std::string`.

Comment: @angel: You are not adding the strings to the vector. You are adding pointers to the strings to the vector. The vector does not touch the strings themselves. If you use the same memory for all the strings, the pointers will all point to the same place.

Comment: It is called in the yacc/bison based program.where I'm trying to write a compiler for a specific grammer.I tried tracing mycode and it seems that in the enter it works fine since e.g after adding a I will get a.then after adding b->ab;b.the second element is write so the problem should'nt be char*.but I will check your suggestionstoo.

Comment: thanks all for their suggestions. the problem was with the pointer in calling enter and ofcourse char*!

Answer (score 4):

You can't use character pointers like that - you need to allocate storage to them. But as you are using C++, you should remove them and replace them with instances of the std::string class, which will manage storage for you.

Comment: C strings *can* be used correctly, even if they are often not. The code she posted is not inherently wrong. It just leaves the responsibility of copying strings to the caller, which might be useful in some cases.